# How to link to apps on the myapplication in android

Tags: android, redirect, share

I am creating a android's application for store app. I want to have a button that takes people to the share apps with telegram. If I use a standard link

http://myappstoreuri/applink

the android opens browser, and then my website.

Any ideas? What is the URL Scheme for the open myapplication ?

Answer (score 0):

Add Intent filter to your Manifest file

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="http"/>
            <data android:host="myappstoreuri"/>
            <data android:pathPrefix="/applink"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

That will ask what app should open this link http://myappstoreuri/applink

But if you need direct link you can write something like

```
        <intent-filter>
            <data android:scheme="myappstore"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        </intent-filter>
```

then every link which starts with myappstore:// will launch your app